# Why do I get an including <iostream.h>?

Tags: c++, iostream

I have been trying to import iostream into a custom block, I added the line

```
 #include <iostream.h>
```

in the .h file and in the .cc file but I get the error:

> fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iostream` header is `<iostream>`, not `<iostream.h>`.  The error you're getting suggests that the compiler is looking for `iostream.h`, which suggests that you might be including the wrong header.

Try changing the header to `<iostream>` and see if that fixes the problem.  More generally, make sure you aren't including any C++ standard library header files suffixed with `.h` unless they come from C as well (in which case you should probably use the C++ versions of the headers anyway).

Hope this helps!